# Bootstrap 5 column with navbar in full screen

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design, bootstrap-5, fullscreen

I want to make this modification using Bootstrap rules and I don't want to change the original CSS files. Can you help me with how to make this 5 same width card (column) a full screen with a navbar?

Problem 1: I see all the time on the desktop a vertical scroll bar.

Problem 2: Navbar is not the same width as this 5 column. It should be the same width, it's OK if not 100%.

Problem 3: All 5 cards touch each other. Please add a few pixel space distance between the cards.

Problem 4: there should be a full screen at most of all resolutions, no vertical scrolls. If it's a really small resolution, it's OK to be in 2 or 1 column. It should be a full screen without vertical and horizontal in bigger resolution, like at 1500 px or at 1200px too. But bigger than this is 5 columns and there is a full screen, no vertical/horizontal scrolls in browser.

Thank you.

```html
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <title>q</title>
  <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-Zenh87qX5JnK2Jl0vWa8Ck2rdkQ2Bzep5IDxbcnCeuOxjzrPF/et3URy9Bv1WTRi" crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>

<body>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-OERcA2EqjJCMA+/3y+gxIOqMEjwtxJY7qPCqsdltbNJuaOe923+mo//f6V8Qbsw3" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <div class="row d-flex justify-content-center">
    <div class="col-lg-2 col-md-6 card" align="center">
      <a href="#1"><img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/2/25/Alice_%28apple%29.jpg" class="card-img-top img-fluid" alt=" " /></a>
      <div class="card-body">
        <p class="card-text" align="center"><a href="#2" class="btn btn-primary">apple</a> </p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-2 col-md-6 card" align="center">
      <a href="#1"><img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/2/25/Alice_%28apple%29.jpg" class="card-img-top img-fluid" alt=" " /></a>
      <div class="card-body">
        <p class="card-text" align="center"><a href="#2" class="btn btn-primary">apple</a> </p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-2 col-md-6 card" align="center">
      <a href="#1"><img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/2/25/Alice_%28apple%29.jpg" class="card-img-top img-fluid" alt=" " /></a>
      <div class="card-body">
        <p class="card-text" align="center"><a href="#2" class="btn btn-primary">apple</a> </p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-2 col-md-6 card" align="center">
      <a href="#1"><img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/2/25/Alice_%28apple%29.jpg" class="card-img-top img-fluid" alt=" " /></a>
      <div class="card-body">
        <p class="card-text" align="center"><a href="#2" class="btn btn-primary">apple</a> </p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-2 col-md-6 card" align="center">
      <a href="#1"><img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/2/25/Alice_%28apple%29.jpg" class="card-img-top img-fluid" alt=" " /></a>
      <div class="card-body">
        <p class="card-text" align="center"><a href="#2" class="btn btn-primary">apple</a> </p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <nav class="navbar bg-light">
    <div class="container-fluid"> <a class="navbar-brand">Navbar</a>
      <form class="d-flex" role="search">
        <input class="form-control me-2" type="search" placeholder="Search" aria-label="Search">
        <button class="btn btn-outline-success" type="submit">Search</button>
      </form>
    </div>
  </nav>
</body>
```

Comment: You _shouldn't_ change the original files of _any_ library. That's just bad practice. If anything you'd load a custom stylesheet with overrides.

Comment: Please see [ask]. You've asked many questions in one post here, which makes your question off topic.

Answer (score 1):

1. I think you meant a *horizontal* scroll bar. That's because you're missing a container element around the rows, as seen in the [Bootstrap Grid docs](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.2/layout/grid/#example).
2. Your cards don't take full width because you're only using 10 of the 12 columns. You can remove that restriction or simply use Bootstrap's flexbox classes instead of rows and columns. I'm not entirely sure what behavior you want.
3. It's generally best to not mix your grid and your content. Put the cards *inside* the columns, which have spacing "gutters" by default.

```html
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <title>q</title>
  <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-Zenh87qX5JnK2Jl0vWa8Ck2rdkQ2Bzep5IDxbcnCeuOxjzrPF/et3URy9Bv1WTRi" crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>

<body>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-OERcA2EqjJCMA+/3y+gxIOqMEjwtxJY7qPCqsdltbNJuaOe923+mo//f6V8Qbsw3" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row d-flex justify-content-center">
      <div class="col">
        <div class="card" align="center">
          <a href="#1"><img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/2/25/Alice_%28apple%29.jpg" class="card-img-top img-fluid" alt=" " /></a>
          <div class="card-body">
            <p class="card-text" align="center"><a href="#2" class="btn btn-primary">apple</a> </p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="col">
        <div class="card" align="center">
          <a href="#1"><img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/2/25/Alice_%28apple%29.jpg" class="card-img-top img-fluid" alt=" " /></a>
          <div class="card-body">
            <p class="card-text" align="center"><a href="#2" class="btn btn-primary">apple</a> </p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="col">
        <div class="card" align="center">
          <a href="#1"><img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/2/25/Alice_%28apple%29.jpg" class="card-img-top img-fluid" alt=" " /></a>
          <div class="card-body">
            <p class="card-text" align="center"><a href="#2" class="btn btn-primary">apple</a> </p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="col">
        <div class="card" align="center">
          <a href="#1"><img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/2/25/Alice_%28apple%29.jpg" class="card-img-top img-fluid" alt=" " /></a>
          <div class="card-body">
            <p class="card-text" align="center"><a href="#2" class="btn btn-primary">apple</a> </p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="col">
        <div class="card" align="center">
          <a href="#1"><img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/2/25/Alice_%28apple%29.jpg" class="card-img-top img-fluid" alt=" " /></a>
          <div class="card-body">
            <p class="card-text" align="center"><a href="#2" class="btn btn-primary">apple</a> </p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <nav class="navbar bg-light">
    <div class="container-fluid"> <a class="navbar-brand">Navbar</a>
      <form class="d-flex" role="search">
        <input class="form-control me-2" type="search" placeholder="Search" aria-label="Search">
        <button class="btn btn-outline-success" type="submit">Search</button>
      </form>
    </div>
  </nav>
</body>
```

Comment: Hi, nearly perfect, isherwood. 
Issue1: in mobile full screen at FullHD resolution should be in 1080p width 2 column not 1. And in 1920p width should be 5 column, not 2. 

Issue2: at desktop if I resize, I sometimes I see 4 small and 1 big image. Should be all of 5 is all times same size. Issue3: can you do this as a new version if 10 column stay, but navbar will be 10 column width?

The navbar is perfect! All others are perfect!